# Ionic: Runtime error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: ionic3

I am in the middle of an Ionic 3 course and while following the course project I faced this error and the stack doesn't show where the error is [screenshot of the error message and the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH2gu.png)

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "."

This is the environment info:

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.6.0
npm  : 6.0.1
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Can someone please advise me how to fix this and if any other information is needed please tell me because I'm not sure exactly what info to add as I don't know what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: this means a path to an import is not pointing to the right spot. Try using an IDE (development tool) that helps us highlight when this happens.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I am using visual studio code and it is not giving me an error that an import is wrong I double checked all the imports. The thing is that it is not stating which module is missing.

Comment: Also check https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52786 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25204 . Should end up resolved in TS3.0

Comment: @SurajRao I double checked and no it's not that problem it was a problem in a previous version.